# How to save to DB CKeditor value by Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, ckeditor, nette

I have project with Nette, Doctrine 2.
When I want save CKeditor value from form by Doctrine 2, It crop same HTML tags and It doesn't save good.
My method save article.

```
public function addArticle($creator, $data) {
    $article = new Article();
    $article->setCategory($data->category);
    $article->setContent($data->content);
    $article->setTitle($data->title);    
    $this->em->persist($article);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

The variable $data->content has value:

```
<h1>My first article</h1>
<p><strong>One bold line</strong></p>
.
.
```

But It saved to database:

```
<h1>My first article</h1>
<p>
```

Do you know, where it's error? How to save CKeditor value with Doctrine 2

Comment: Sorry. :(( I had column in db as varchar(45). I feel bad.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use text instead of string, without lenght value.

> Doctrine 2 text field type:
>
> Maps and converts string data without a maximum length. If you don’t
>   know the maximum length of the data to be stored, you should consider
>   using this type. Values retrieved from the database are always
>   converted to PHP’s string type or null if no data is present.

Comment: Yes, I use that. I have in db model `content text` bud, I don't know, why I created table with `varchar (45)` and I didn't see how I created table. Thank you for your recommendation. How I define column in entity?

Comment: /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="some_field", type="text")
 */
    private $someField;

This is mapped as a longtext field in mySQL.